# how to check my jradio button is selected or not using if statement

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

```
if (radioButton.isSelected())
{
     //do something
}
```

how to check my jradio button is selected or not using if statement... what is "isSelected" here ? sorry,im new to this stuff... tq

Comment: You might want to start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JRadioButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) which clear states "*iSelected() Returns the state of the button. True if the toggle button is selected, false if it's not."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check radioButton selected or not by this code

```
if (radioButton.isSelected()) {
  //do something

}else {
  //do something
}
```

"isSelected()" is a boolean function used to check components selected or not if a component is selected it returns true and if not selected it returns false

For more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected--

Answer (score 0):

JRadioButton inherits [isSelected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected--) method from class javax.swing.AbstractButton 
which states below about its working:-

> public boolean isSelected() 
> Returns the state of the button. True if
>   the toggle button is selected, false if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isSelected` method:

> void setSelected(boolean)
>   boolean isSelected()
>   Set or get whether the button is selected. Makes sense only for buttons that have on/off state, such as check boxes.

example:

```
if (radioButton.isSelected()) {
     doThis();
}else{
    doThat();
}
```

you can reffer more infos [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)